# Definition of local maximum for multivariable functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I want to define the local maximum of multivatriable funcrtion. I did not find any formal definition for that, except for two-variable functions.

Is the following definition correct, generalized from the definition of two-variable function?

> A function $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ has a $\textit{local maximum}$ at the
>   point $(q_0,\cdots,q_n)$ if $f(q_0,\cdots,q_n) \geq
>  f(q_0+\delta_0,\cdots,q_n+\delta_n)$, for all sufficiently small $\pm
>  \delta_i \in \{\delta_0,\cdots,\delta_n\}$.

Comment: The usual definition says something about $f$ in a neighborhood of $q$...

Comment: I want to make the term "neighborhood" more formal.

Comment: you do know there is precise definition of neighborhood...

Comment: I am not aware of the definition of neighborhood

Comment: Cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima?wprov=sfti1 section Definition